# DOMException with dojo, dgrid, TabContainer, and JsonRest

Tags: rest, dojo, grid, tabcontainer

This drove me crazy for a weekend, and although I found what seems to be a workable solution, my question is whether there is something fundamental about using Dojo/Dijit that I'm missing.

Here's the problem: Whenever I create page in which a [dgrid](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid) uses a JsonRest store and is in a hidden tab of a TabContainer (one that is not the initially selected one), I get DOMExceptions and a somewhat screwed up dgrid. In particular, the dgrid has a large empty space under the last row of data, and scrolling to the bottom or top of the dgrid's data throws additional DOMExceptions.

If I click on one of the column headers to sort the dgrid, it resets its layout and works fine. If the dgrid initializes on a visible part of the page instead of an unselected tab, it's fine. If I use a Memory store instead of a JsonRest, everything's fine (even if the dgrid is initialized in a hidden tab). If the dgrid is initialized in a hidden tab but without a store, it's fine (but empty).

Based on the evidence, I guessed the problem had something to do with the fact that a JsonRest query takes time, and for some reason that's breaking dgrid when it's initializing. My solution was to create the dgrid without a store, and then set the store when its the tab containing the dgrid was shown. This seems kludgy, though. I should be able to create a dgrid with a store and not have to fiddle with it externally.

So, is my somewhat hack-ish solution the proper (or at least a reasonable) way to handle initializing a hidden dgrid with server-supplied data, or is there something about the setup of TabContainer+dgrid+JsonRest that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer to your question, but there is a contract between Dijit widgets and containers regarding the lifecycle and startup of a widget... in particular, when the elements are added to the DOM and, at the end, when the `startup()` method is called to layout and resize the elements.  dgrid probably does not participate.  Perhaps you can connect something to the TabContainer's startup method which will trigger a layout of the dgrid component?

Comment: It would not surprise me if I was breaking a contract somewhere; the details of the Dijit lifecycle are still a bit vague to me.The dgrid is actually contained within a ContentPane. Well, to be more correct it is the ContentPane's domNode (in the CP's postCreate, I use its domNode as the attachment point for the grid, as in `var grid = declare([Grid, DijitRegistry], {...}, this.domNode)`). That appears to work insofar as the grid resizes itself as the ContentPane once the containing tab becomes selected.